# Set CAN Filter to a specific ID STM32

Tags: stm32, can-bus, hal

I need to set a CAN Filter to ID "$7E8". But I need to set a ID High, Low and a Mask.

```
    FilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    FilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    FilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    FilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
```

I found this Article: https://schulz-m.github.io/2017/03/23/stm32-can-id-filter/

And tried that code:

```
    FilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x00000008;
    FilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x00000008;
    FilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x1FFFFFFF;
    FilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x1FFFFFFF;
```

But it doesn't recognise a message sent with $7E8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. `id0` and `id1` are two message IDs you want to allow (in ID list mode, you always set two per filter bank). If you want to set just one, I assume you can repeat the first one.

```
CAN_FilterTypeDef filter;
filter.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
filter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;

// Allow two IDs per entry
filter.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
filter.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST;

// Mask seems to have no effect when using CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST
filter.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
filter.FilterMaskIdLow  = 0x0000;

filter.FilterIdLow  = id0;
filter.FilterIdHigh = id1;

filter.FilterBank = 0;

if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(hcan, &filter)) {
    Error_Handler();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2 corrections:

1. When using CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT in combination with CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST the mask high and mask low variables also contain 11-bit-IDs. You can set a filter bank for 4 11-bit-IDs with ID list mode this way.
2. The ID needs to be shifted to the correct position in the corresponding register. This is different for 16 Bit and 32 Bit scale. For 32 bit scale refer to the microcontroller reference manual. For 16 bit scale here is an example:

```
  CAN_FilterTypeDef tsCanFilter = { 0 };

  tsCanFilter.FilterActivation     = ENABLE;
  tsCanFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FILTER_FIFO0;
  tsCanFilter.FilterScale          = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
  tsCanFilter.FilterMode           = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDLIST;
  
  tsCanFilter.FilterIdLow          = u32Id1 << 5u;
  tsCanFilter.FilterMaskIdLow      = u32Id2 << 5u;
  tsCanFilter.FilterIdHigh         = u32Id3 << 5u;
  tsCanFilter.FilterMaskIdHigh     = u32Id4 << 5u;

  tsCanFilter.FilterBank           = 0u;
  
  if ( HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter ( &tsCanHandle, &tsCanFilter ) != HAL_OK )
  {
    // error handling
  }
```